# How to Include html tags inside consoleFull log in Jenkins from python script

Tags: python, html, jenkins, logging, console

I am trying to include a html **<a id=Section1> Section1 </a>'** tag inside an console log. I printed same in my python3 script  as **print('<a id=Section1> Section1 </a>')**, but it is coming as a raw string in consoleFull log.

If I achieve this I can have a href link to particular section of the log, by using **<a href="jenkinsJob:8080/job/RunJob/123/consoleFull#Section1">link to Section1</a>**

Please suggest any plugins available in Jenkins or is there a way to handle in python.

Comment: by console log, do you mean browser's console.log

Comment: yes, in browser's console log        
ex: output in browser log: 18:15:32 <a id=Section1> Section1 </a>